# How to create info boxes in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need to create text boxes 3 of same length and the other one along column box in same row. and then again 3 text boxes in next row. I am using card classes. Problem is to adjust the boxes in empty space below first row.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px; padding:10px;">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-deck" >
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <p>This is text inside the first card</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <p>This is text inside the first card</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <p>This is text inside the first card</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <p class="card-text">Some text inside the first card jdnjfewhjhjdvnjerjrhifhfdjnvjerhggjew</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text inside the first card jdnjfewhjhjdvnjerjrhifhfdjnvjerhggjew</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text inside the first card jdnjfewhjhjdvnjerjrhifhfdjnvjerhggjew</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-deck" >
            <div class="card bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <p>This is text inside the first card</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <p>This is text inside the first card</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting the boxes in empty space below first row? You want those 3 boxes in the second row merge into those 4 boxes on the first row? Like Masonry style?

Comment: Row1 : height of first three boxes is same and of last box is larger it is column . the Row2: the boxes should come immediately below above boxes and the rest of space should be occupied by last box of first row (one with large height).

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this is easy, because you can use `.card-columns` to achieve that. But then I realized cards in `.card-columns` are ordered from the top to bottom, and then from the left to right.

Using the `.row` and `.col-*` is the only way I can think of right way to get what you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
                <div class="col-4">card with short text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            card with long text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/111581/

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot David Liang. you sort my problem :)